# How to assign DataFrame observations to groups according to a particular distribution?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame where each observation (row) represents a person.

I want to assign every person who satisfies a particular condition to different groups. I need this because my final aim is to create a network and link the persons in the same groups with some probabilities depeneding on the group.

So, for instance, I want to assign all children aged between 6 and 10 to schools. Then in the end I will create links between the children in the same school with a particular probability *p*.

I know the size distribution of the schools in the area I want to simulate.
So I want to draw school sizes from this distribution and then "fill up" the schools with all the children aged from 6 to 10.

I am new to pandas: the way I was thinking to do this was to create a new column, fill it up with NaN and then just assign a school ID to the different students.

Let's say my DataFrame `df` is this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': range(11), 'AGE': [15, 6, 54, 8, 10, 39, 2, 7, 9, 10, 6]})

df
Out[1]: 
    AGE  ID
0    15   0
1     6   1
2    54   2
3     8   3
4    10   4
5    39   5
6     2   6
7     7   7
8     9   8
9    10   9
10    6  10
```

(Incidentally, I don't know how to put the ID column first, but anyway in real life I'm reading the dataframe from a CSV file so that's not a problem).

Now, what I'd like to do is create another column, `ELEM_SCHOOL_ID`, initialize it to `NaN` and just assign values to those who are the right age.

What I have succeded to do until now is: create a subset of the DataFrame with the persons who satisfy the age condition.

```
df['IN_ELEM_SCH'] = np.where((df['AGE']>5) & (df['AGE']<11), 'True', 'False')
df
Out[2]: 
    AGE  ID IN_ELEM_SCH
0    15   0       False
1     6   1        True
2    54   2       False
3     8   3        True
4    10   4        True
5    39   5       False
6     2   6       False
7     7   7        True
8     9   8        True
9    10   9        True
10    6  10        True
```

Then, I would need to add another column, `ELEM_SCHOOL_ID` that contains the ID of the particular elementary school every student is attending.

I can initialize the new column with:

```
df["ELEM_SCHOOL_ID"] = np.nan
df
Out[84]: 
    AGE  ID IN_ELEM_SCH  SCHOOL_ID
0    15   0       False        NaN
1     6   1        True        NaN
2    54   2       False        NaN
3     8   3        True        NaN
4    10   4        True        NaN
5    39   5       False        NaN
6     2   6       False        NaN
7     7   7        True        NaN
8     9   8        True        NaN
9    10   9        True        NaN
10    6  10        True        NaN
```

What I want to do now is:

1. Draw a number from the school size distribution: *n0*
2. For *n0* random persons satisfying the age condition (so those who have `IN_ELEM_SCHOOL == True`), assign `0` to `SCHOOL_ID`
3. Draw another number from the school size distribution: *n1*
4. For *n1* random persons still not assigned to a school, assign `1` to `SCHOOL_ID`
5. Repeat until all the persons with IN_ELEM_SCH == True have been assigned a school ID.

So, for example, let's say that the first school size drawn from the distribution is `n0=2`, the second `n1=3` and the third `n2=4`.
I want to end up with something like this:

```
    AGE  ID IN_ELEM_SCH  SCHOOL_ID
0    15   0       False        NaN
1     6   1        True        0
2    54   2       False        NaN
3     8   3        True        1
4    10   4        True        2
5    39   5       False        NaN
6     2   6       False        NaN
7     7   7        True        1
8     9   8        True        1
9    10   9        True        2
10    6  10        True        0
```

In real life, the school size is distributed as a lognormal distribution. Say, with parameters `mu = 4` and `sigma = 1`
I can then draw from this distribution:

```
s = np.random.lognormal(mu, sigma, 100)
```

But I still wasn't able to figure out how to assign the schools.

I apologize for the length of this question, but I wanted to be clear.

Thank you very much for any hint or help you could give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas will automatically match on the index when assigning new data. Checkout the pandas [docs on indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing).

Note: You wouldn't normally create the extra `IN_ELEM_SCHOOL` column (i.e. third line in the code below is unnecessary).

```
mu, sigma = 1, 0.5

m = (5 < df['AGE']) & (df['AGE'] < 11)
df['IN_ELEM_SCHOOL'] = m

s = m[m].sample(frac=1)

n, i = 0, 0
while n < len(s):
    num_students = int(np.random.lognormal(mu, sigma))
    s[n: n + num_students] = i
    i += 1
    n += num_students
df['SCHOOL_ID'] = s
df
```

returns

```
    AGE  ID  IN_ELEM_SCHOOL  SCHOOL_ID
0    15   0           False        NaN
1     6   1            True        0.0
2    54   2           False        NaN
3     8   3            True        1.0
4    10   4            True        2.0
5    39   5           False        NaN
6     2   6           False        NaN
7     7   7            True        1.0
8     9   8            True        0.0
9    10   9            True        0.0
10    6  10            True        1.0
```

Comment: Thank you, that looks good, but I don't need to assign to each person a number drawn from the lognormal distribution. That's the school size. So if the first number drawn, say, is 12, I want to put 12 random persons in the first school, assigning the first SCHOOL_ID (0 in my example) to them. Then if the second number drawn is 45, I want to assign to 45 persons at random satisfying the age condition the second SCHOOL_ID, 1. And so on until all those satisfying the age condition are assigned to a school.